# ruby regex : match any .css filename not starting with an underscore, preceding any string

Tags: ruby, regex, expression

I'm trying to figure out how I can match any .css filename, not starting with an underscore, preceding any string. I found a good starting point from this question on stackoverflow ([ActiveAdmin assets precompile error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8592156/activeadmin-assets-precompile-error)) :

```
[/^[^_]\w+\.(css|css.scss)$/]
```

However, this regex only matches filename.css without an underscore. I'd like to have a regex that matches any path before the filename without underscore. The following strings should match :

```
mystyle.css
application.css.scss
/assets/stylesheets/application.css
```

but the following strings should not match :

```
_mystyle.css
_application.css.scss
/assets/stylesheets/_application.css
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Something like this should work:

`/(.+\/|^)[a-z0-9\.]+\.s?css$/`

Not all ruby versions support it, but you coul also try a negative lookahead:

`/.+\/?(?!_)\w+\.s?css$/`

http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.0/Regexp.html#label-Anchors

Comment: the negative lookahead didn't work for me. The other one does! Thank u.

Comment: The second version is incorrect. The lookahead fails because the previous `.+` can just match past it if it wants to - the slash is optional. And the first version doesn't allow an underscore (or an uppercase letter) anywhere in the filename...

Answer (score 2):

This should work:

```
/^(.*?\/)?[^_]\w*\.(css|css\.scss)$/
```

Explanation:

```
(.*?\/)?  # Means it accepts any characters upfront, ending with a slash, 
          # then the filename. The ? makes it optional.
```

Comment: Reading through and understanding http://www.regular-expressions.info/tutorial.html is a great start. You can also use online tools to test regex such as http://regex101.com/ while reading the tutorial, which will also tell you what each part of a regex does.

Comment: You should mark an answer as accepted if it solved your problem, to help others find the correct answer if they google your question.

Comment: Note that this regex will fail to match filenames that are only one character in length (like `a.css`).

Comment: @TimPietzcker You are, as always, correct. I shamelessly copied the rest of the regex. I'll update the answer.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that the input is always a file path, I would prefer to do like this:

```
File.basename(file_path).match(/_.*(css|scss|sass)/)
```

Regexps are hard to read, and so to improve your code readability is a good idea to use as few as necessary.

Also, if you are doing other matches, you might want to extract the css file extensions in other regexp like

```
css_exts_regexp = /(css|scss|sass)/
 File.basename(file_path).match(/_.*#{css_exts_regxp}/)
```

Comment: Depending on whether this is a valid option, this is a better solution than any regex.

Comment: I can't really use this solution because the file_path is an unknown factor in my case. I have to provide the regex in this form : config.assets.precompile += [/^[^_]\w+\.(css|css.scss)$/] .